# Why is my function not working in my Python script on the first file?

Tags: python-3.x, function

I have a Python script that walks through folders and if it finds one that is a TIFF image that it calls my function and converts it to a JPEG and resizes it.  It works to create the JPEG but it doesn't resize the first image it finds in the folders.  After the first image the next one is converted properly.  The code looks fine and nothing I am seeing in the function is an issue.  Can anyone offer assistance on the reason?

Here is my main script:

```
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(src):
    #Looping through all of the files in the Approved folders
    for file in files:
        if file != 'Thumbs.db' and file != '.DS_Store':
          if minutesOld >= minutes: # <-- We'll only copy the file if it's five minutes old or older.
            if file.lower().endswith('.tif'): # <-- If file is a TIFF file and there are no errors yet
                    try:
                        image_convert(filepath,'.jpg','RGB',2500,2500)
                    
                    except:
                        error
```

Here is my function code:

```
def image_convert(filepath,imageType,colorMode,height,width):
    imwrite(filepath[:-4] + imageType, imread(filepath)[:,:,:3].copy()) # <-- using the imagecodecs library function of imread, make a copy in memory of the TIFF File.
    # The :3 on the end of the numpy array is stripping the alpha channel from the TIFF file if it has one so it can be easily converted to a JPEG file.
    # Once the copy is made the imwrite function is creating a JPEG file from the TIFF file.
    # The [:-4] is stripping off the .tif extension from the file and the + '.jpg' is adding the .jpg extension to the newly created JPEG file.
    img = Image.open(filepath[:-4] + imageType) # <-- Using the Image.open function from the Pillow library, we are getting the newly created JPEG file and opening it.
    img = img.convert(colorMode) # <-- Using the convert function we are making sure to convert the JPEG file to RGB color mode.
    img = img.resize((height, width)) # <-- Using the resize function we are resizing the JPEG to 2500 x 2500
    return(img)
```

Comment: I'm surprised _any_ image is resized at all, given that you `imwrite` the original image but never the resized one.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi that line of code is reading the TIFF image in memory and writing the jpeg image from that.  It works fine if I put it inline but when I do a function call it only resizes the final image file that it comes to.

Comment: It resizes everything. What do you do with the image that is returned from `image_convert`?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi when I run the code and call the function it is only resizing the last file it comes to.  To answer your question, once it's converted it is resized.

Comment: Your resized image is in `img` inside `image_convert()`. Once this is returned, you don't seem to do anything with it. When you say "doesn't resize", do you mean the `.jpg` file written isn't resized or that `img` isn't resized? Because `img` _always_ gets resized, but you also need to write it somewhere or do something else with it once it's returned from `image_convert`.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi the .jpg file written isn't resized. It only resizes the last file it comes to in the iteration through the folders.  What do I need to do to adjust this function to make it work on all images?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this wasn't working correctly is because it was missing the line of code to save the resized image.  This is the revised code that works:

```
def image_convert(filepath,imageType,colorMode,height,width):
    imwrite(filepath[:-4] + imageType, imread(filepath)[:,:,:3].copy()) # <-- using the imagecodecs library function of imread, make a copy in memory of the TIFF File.
    # The :3 on the end of the numpy array is stripping the alpha channel from the TIFF file if it has one so it can be easily converted to a JPEG file.
    # Once the copy is made the imwrite function is creating a JPEG file from the TIFF file.
    # The [:-4] is stripping off the .tif extension from the file and the + '.jpg' is adding the .jpg extension to the newly created JPEG file.
    img = Image.open(filepath[:-4] + imageType) # <-- Using the Image.open function from the Pillow library, we are getting the newly created JPEG file and opening it.
    img = img.convert(colorMode) # <-- Using the convert function we are making sure to convert the JPEG file to RGB color mode.
    imageResize = img.resize((height, width)) # <-- Using the resize function we are resizing the JPEG to 2500 x 2500
    imageResize.save(filepath[:-4] + imageType) # <-- Using the save function, we are saving the newly sized JPEG file over the original JPEG file initially created.
    return(imageResize)
```